# Zookeeper Star. Error on start and Stopped | Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, apache-zookeeper

Try to run Zookeeper. Do such [in this instruction](https://www.edureka.co/community/39059/installing-zookeeper-on-windows)

There are my settings

[Envirement Ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BPbR.png)

And my path

[Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcT07.png)
First of all I want to say that I try to run zookeper such way `zkserver` and I have a massege in promt

`\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 was unexpected at this time.`

Then I try to start such way `zkServer.sh start` I have the result 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYuh5.png)
After start I see `stopped` for one second and zookeeper turn off. I oppend log files and see this

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWvFZ.png)

Comment: Hey have to change anything in zoo.cfg file?

Comment: I created copy of zoo_sample.cfg, names it zoo.cfg and change the path to this(sucth in instraction) http://prntscr.com/se6dnm

Comment: Do 2 things and check, the first check in your zoo.cfg file while copy and paste the path by mistake any special should not be there..For this you can open the zoo.cfg file in notepad++ (view->show symbol->show all character) and second start zookeeper with `./zkServer.sh start-foreground`  command... and check still you are seeing any error logs in console.

Comment: I have this in oppend console http://prntscr.com/se7n11 . I checked all lines of file. There are no mistakes